# How do I play movies from the Google Play store in WMC?

Tags: windows-media-center

I saw an ad indicating Game Of Thrones Season 4 is available on Google Play today. I have a Windows Media Centre based HTPC. Is there any way I can watch Google Play content from within WMC?

Comment: You can download the video using the Amazon Video app on PC then indicate to WMC it should look at that folder

Comment: [This one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/video/ontv/player)?

Comment: Only A`mazon Video` application on the internet